# Power converter topology

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I was reading a patent on wireless power transfer and I am trying to understand the associated schematic, which is:

[image: circuit diagram]

The patent describes the operation by saying that the charge transistor (10) is switched ON while the discharge transistor (12) is switched OFF then 10 is OFF and 12 is switched ON. The output is noted 16 and 5 is a current transformer.

What topology is this circuit? I don't understand the operation.

Comment: Welcome. If an image is taken from somewhere it's always good to give a link to the source (article, patent, web page, etc). Please put a link to the patent.